# Get user's location at a specific time and date in iOS

Tags: ios, location, cllocationmanager, background-mode

I have an app where I create events. I need to get user's location when the event is ending automatically (set by user while creating event). I tried local notification but in that case, you need to wait for user's interaction and that can cause delay as user might not click right away.

I want user's exact location at a specific time regardless of the state of the app (foreground, background or not running). Let me know if you need any further clarification. Also, any document, tutorial or code will be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can't do this. There is no way to execute code at a specific time if your app isn't in the foreground.

Comment: Is there any work around for it ? I know voip allows you to open even terminated app. Is there anything I can use for time or location based even when app is not running ? Anything ??

Comment: If your app is a VoIP app then you could use a VoIP push to launch your app in the background at a specific time, but otherwise, no.

Comment: No, my app is not using voip but I am using location. Is it possible to run location in background mode even when app is terminated ?

Comment: Can I use push kit to call silent notification ? Will it work for non-voip purpose ?

Comment: You can use continuous background location updating, but this will drain the device battery.  If the user terminates your app then you will no longer receive updates.  You can't use push kit for non-VoIP apps (It *will work*, but you will get rejected by Apple review)

Comment: So, basically there's nothing I can do but call a local notification and hope user will click on it at that instant to get the correct location. :/ It sucks.

Comment: If there is an incentive to the user to provide their location then maybe you can assume that they will respond to the notification or that they will let your app run in the background with location updates.

Comment: Yeah. I understand and thats the only hope. Thank you.

Comment: You could register for Significant Location Change so your app would be called every time there is a location change (of about 500m). Each time it's called you could store the location off with a time stamp. Then when the event ends, fire off your localNotification. The action of the notification would grab the last location update that doesn't exceed the event end date/time.  It's not perfect but it would get you within a few 100 meters.

Comment: @rmp, Actually thats how I implemented then because that is closest to what I expect. Thank you for reply.